# How do I close all pages after changing an item's data?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a doubt in Xamarin forms, I have an application that I would like after finishing the training, it closes all the training screens and only the main screen remains, today I got a cod that does this, but when I restart the app and I login,
when he closes the screens instead of going back to the main screen he goes back to the login, I'm not using masterpage, could that be it?

source:

```
 private async void BtnVoltar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      

        int numModals = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count;

        // Pop each modal in the stack
        for (int currModal = 0; currModal < numModals; currModal++)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new TabbedPageMenu());
    }
```

Image Link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbNjK.jpg

Another doubt would be after updating the data of an item, if it is possible to close the two screens and update it on the main screen

image link2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn80P.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method to navigate to the different pages instead of close the pages.

The code in `xaml` you can add the command to do the navigation.

```
Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
CommandParameter="{x:Type views:targetpagename}"
```

The code in `xaml.cs` or viewmodel

```
public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigateCommand = new Command<Type>(
            async (Type pageType) =>
            {
                Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            });

        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Comment: But if I press the back button on the screen, it would not go back to the previous one, I just need it to close when I modify screen 4 of the first image and screen 3 of the second image